# How to downgrade to perl 5.10.1?

Tags: perl, downgrade

I'm running into lots of issues with perl modules requiring `perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)`:

```
Error: Package: perl-Class-MOP-1.12-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)
Error: Package: perl-Moose-1.15-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)
```

The installed perl version is 5.16.3, OS is Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.03, and I'd very much like to downgrade to perl 5.10.1 so that the compat issues are fixed. How do I do this?

This happens in particular when I try to install perl-Net-Amazon-EC2, here's what `yum list shows`:

`perl-Net-Amazon-EC2.noarch 0.14-2.el6 epel`

So it's coming from epel and here's a corresponding section of repo file:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

Seems like version in repo is 0.14 and the latest is 0.24 (I've tried installing it manually, but it did not work and I in any case don't want to install manually for all the packages)

Comment: Where are you getting these packages from?

Comment: The best thing is probably to just add a new Perl installation of 5.10.1 rather than downgrading (which would be messy).  There is a lot of help out there for managing multiple Perl installations.  See http://perlbrew.pl/, for example.

Comment: @Richard Huxton, `yum install perl-Moose` and `yum install perl-Net-Amazon-EC2` both fail due to this.

Comment: Then either the packaging for Amazon Linux is broken or you've broken your packaging configuration. Those don't appear to be Perl errors - I'm guessing it's yum complaining that the new package is the wrong version.

Comment: @Richard Huxton, I haven't made any changes to the AMI - started from console.aws.amazon.com, ssh'ed into instanse, ran yum install, got error.

Comment: @dan111, Re "The best thing is probably to just add a new Perl installation of 5.10.1 rather than downgrading", he wouldn't be using the packages, so he wouldn't have to install 5.10.1. If he installs his own Perl, he should install the latest.

Comment: @ikegami - perhaps, but yum is trying to install Perl 5.10 packages and his perl is 5.16.3 - something is broken.

Comment: I don't know if you can add some debug or verbose flag to your yum calls, or if there is some other way to find out where these packages are coming from. However, it seems very likely they are coming from the wrong repository.

Comment: @Richard Huxton, I've updated the question with repo it's coming from.

Comment: @ikegami - yes, was intended for you, but didn't see that you were responding to dan111. Ignore my blather.

Comment: Clearly the epel repository shouldn't be there. According to http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/latest-release-notes/ Perl was upgraded and presumably some yum settings weren't updated. I would go through all the yum repos configured and just check they're all the right ones.

Comment: @Richard Huxton, with `--disablerepo=epel` the package won't install at all. How do I verify correctness of a yum repo? Is it possible that an rpm for that module supporting anything other than perl 5.10 was never created and pushed to a repo?

Comment: Can't help you there I'm afraid. You'll need to consult the amazon docs / support. I'm a Debian man myself.

Comment: @ikegami, yes, maybe the premise of the question should be challenged.  But given the assumption that Perl 5.10 needs to be installed, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is install [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl). It is Linux/Unix specific, and uses BASH. If you use Zsh or Kornshell, you need to munge the scripts a wee bit. If you're on Windows, well... good luck.

Perlbrew will allow you to install multiple versions of Perl as user installed Perls. You don't need root permission to use these various versions of Perl You can also run CPAN via Perlbrew to install modules in the various versions of Perl. This is a great way to install multiple versions of Perl for testing purposes. My default Perl is 5.16, so I've installed 5.18 to get the latest, 5.10, 5.12, and 5.8.9 to match as closely as possible the version of Perl we run on our RHEL servers.

To switch from one version of Perl to another, you use this command:

```
$ perlbrew use 5.10   # Use this version in the current shell
```

or

```
$ perlbrew switch 5.10  # This is now your default version of Perl
```

To install a particular version of Perl:

```
$ perlbrew install 5.10  # I'm installing Perl 5.10!
```

Perlbrew uses `$PATH` to set your Perl version, so you need to be careful with your shebang. You're not necessarily running Perl under `/usr/bin/perl` anymore. You shebang in your Perl scripts should be:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
```

Way easier than attempting to downgrade your default installed Perl.

Comment: I tried this but when I try to install any version with perlbrew I got the error: `Page not retrieved; HTTP error code 400 or above. at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/App/perlbrew.pm line 228.`

Comment: @Fabiotk, % perlbrew available

Comment: You need to do two things, first create the directories necessary and then use the minor version to make the installation as in `cd ; mkdir perl5/; mkdir perl5/perlbrew/; mkdir perl5/perlbrew/dists` and then `perlbrew install perl-5.16.0`